# Executing two commands together in command line

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I followed previous threads:

I want to execute shell file and write into text parallel. Content should be written first in text file and the shell file should be executed.

```
# input.txt < "I love cat, she is nice" && ./test.sh
bash: I love cat, she is nice: No such file or directory
```

Another try:

```
# ./test.sh && input.txt < "I love cat, she is nice"
batch processes ..
bash: I love cat, she is nice: No such file or directory
```

What is the correct way?

Comment: If something should happen "first", then there is no "parallel".

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "I love cat, she is nice" > input.txt && ./test.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this - you want a script to create a script and then run it:

```
echo "echo hello" > go.sh && chmod +x go.sh && ./go.sh
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not following?

```
echo "I love cat, she is nice" > input.txt; ./test.sh
```

Comment: @  user3449212: I did not downvote you. I actually think it is a useful question.